# Read online json file in faster way php

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents` to read online json URL 
and i don't have `cURL` installed any advised how to make my request faster

Thanks, 
Mariana

Comment: Maybe the response from the server is slow? There may not be much you can do about it. Can you cache the data so you don't have to make the external call for every request?

Answer (score 1):

**Do Some simple benchmarking:**

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    $handle = fopen("http://example.com/", "r");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $result .= fread($handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;

echo "Did fopen test in $time seconds<br />\n";
?>
```

**Did fopen test in 6.1602981090546 seconds**

```
<?php
//file_get_contents is basically a wrapper for the above fopen so hence not much of a difference
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    $result = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
}
$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;

echo "Did file_get_contents test in $time seconds<br />\n";
?>
```

**Did file_get_contents test in 6.5289459228516 seconds**

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;

echo "Did cUrl test in $time seconds<br />\n";
?>
```

**Did cUrl test in 2.9657130241394 seconds**

*cURL wins hands down... time to look for a better host*

Answer (score 0):

Either way sould be fast.
http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/php_benchmarking_fopen

Theres not better.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a way to make your request faster. What you can do is cache the data locally if it does not change a lot.

Pseudocode:

```
if (get_modification_time_of_file('cached.json') < time() - 300) {
    download_file()
} else {
    read_locally()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1: By using the fopen/file_get_contents function(s)

2: By setting a client side bridge and sending it to php via a POST method using AJAX. then get it on the PHP using json_decode.